# Orchard CMS: Is it possible to add BeforeContent, Content, and AfterContent content when editing a content page?

Tags: orchardcms

Is it possible when editing a content page to have a text box for Content, BeforeContent, and AfterContent?

I would like to break up my articles into sections such as introduction, core, and summary so that each part gets styled differently in the Layout.cshtml. The only way I can think to do this is to create a layer for each content page then add html widgets for the BeforeContent and AfterContent zones that I would put my introduction and summary in. This seems like alot of extra work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, add fields and set-up placement for them. Widgets will work too but it will be more painful to maintain. If not almost impossible.

Comment: Any chance for HTML fields? Doesn't look like it's a field.

Comment: Yes it is. Just add a text field, and then configure it for HTML.